# DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT returning different results in different oracle DB versions

Tags: database, oracle, encryption, oracle11g, oracle19c

I got an annoying issue I'm out of ideas with. When using the DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT function of the oracle dbms_crypto package I get a different result in oracle 11C and oracle 19. I first noticed this issue when migrating a database from 11c to 19c and running into issue decrypting stored values.

The following sql query illustrates this issue:

```
select rawtohex(DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT(src => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('TOENCRYPT', 'AL32UTF8'),typ => 5128 ,key => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('e24WwDYbk25wqe5pevJ3g3VJgyjXr6HX', 'AL32UTF8'))) from dual;
```

In oracle 11c this query returns `9A18D619A269A5AF9716F2869A8A4F5F` while in oracle 19c it returns `049AFACC8EC7AE239EC496E5B4534048`.

I have been trying to figure out what could cause this difference. I checked the sub-parts of the query and I isolated the first difference to the output of the encrypt function.

I also checked with different databases of 11g and the query always gave the same result.

Did someone else encounter this issue before and knows how to solve this? Or can someone give me some pointers as to what would influence the functions from the query?

Comment: Have you tried with different values of `typ`?

Comment: There is only one documented compatibility issue when upgrading from 11g to 12c: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/manually-encrypting-data.html#GUID-40DE97DD-7CD5-486C-B9FB-959408BF6081. If you think this difference is  a bug, you should contact Oracle support.

Comment: Can reproduce. The result changes between 11.2 (`9A18D`...) and 12.1 (`049AF`...) and is then constant up to 19.3

Comment: @pifor was on the money. It was indeed related to this bug. I can't believe I did not find that documentation myself. I will accept wolφi as the answer untill/unless pifor makes an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TenG's hint was spot on.

```
typ = 5128 = 0x1408 
             0x1000 PAD_PKCS5
             0x0400 CHAIN_OFB
             0x0008 ENCRYPT_AES256

11.2         9A18D619A269A5AF9716F2869A8A4F5F
12.1         049AFACC8EC7AE239EC496E5B4534048
```

According to Oracle Support Doc ID 2014909.1, OFB mode was not properly implemented in 11.2 and was in fact doing the ECB chaining.

```
             0x1000 PAD_PKCS5
             0x0300 CHAIN_ECB
             0x0008 ENCRYPT_AES256
typ = 4872 = 0x1308 

11.2         9A18D619A269A5AF9716F2869A8A4F5F
12.1         9A18D619A269A5AF9716F2869A8A4F5F
```

In other words, in 11.2, if you asked for OFB, you got ECB instead. If you ask for ECB, you get the same value in both versions.